# Deleting Files with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm developing a SharePoint App where I need to delete a number of photos that the user will select, so I have a function that I pass an array with the URLs of the photos that will be deleted, but I don't know why it isn't working. This is the function I'm using!

```
function deleteFiles(arrayURLs) {
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
    var scriptbase = siteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", ejecutarCrossDomain());
    function ejecutarCrossDomain() {
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(webUrl);
        for (var i = 0, len = arrayURLs.length; i < len; i++) {
            var urlRest = webUrl + "/_api/sp.appcontextsite(@target)/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + arrayURLs[i] + "')?@target='" + siteUrl + "'";
            console.log(urlRest)
            executor.executeAsync({
                url: urlRest,
                type: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
                    "IF-MATCH": "*"
                },
                success: succes,
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    loadingOff();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    function succes() {
        console.log('Deleted');
    }
}
```

When I try it, it seems like it work, logging the Deleted in the console too. Thanks to the one that can help me!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Verify the array and the URLs. I modified your script using something similar the following direct API requests so I could do a quick test, and I got your result. My error was an incorrect URL to the files.

Here's a pure AJAX and REST delete that works just fine:

```
$.ajax(
{
    "url": "/sites/test/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/AirplaneLogo.jpg')",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
        "If-Match": "*",
        "X-RequestDigest": "yourRequestDigestGoesHere"
    },
    "success" = successfunction,
    "error" = errorfunction
}
);
```

You can send the items to the Recycle Bin by adding "/recycle()" to the API URL.

A successful Delete returns no data. A successful recycle() returns the GUID for the recycled item.