# How can we permanently delete the file using Microsoft flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

Using delete file action the file is deleted but goes to recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the file(s) permanently using REST API "HTTP DELETE".

```
$.ajax({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared%20Documents')",  
        type: "POST",  
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        headers: {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
            "IF-MATCH": "*",  
            "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",  
        },  
        success: function(data) {  
            alert("success");  
        },  
        error: function(data) {  
            alert("failed");  
        }  
    });
```

You can send the items to the Recycle Bin by adding "/recycle()" to the API URL.

A successful Delete returns no data. A successful recycle() returns the GUID for the recycled item.

[Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239484/deleting-files-with-rest-api)

Comment: santosh is asking to delete the file using Microsoft flow. Not REST api.

Comment: I don't know hard delete using MS Flow so I just provided an alternative.

Comment: @GaneshSanap can we trigger REST API using MS flow else any idea about hard delete file using flow.

Comment: @santoshkalange actually i have never used REST API in flow. but found one URL about same, [here](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-Procedure-to-Call-SharePoint-Office-365-REST-API-from-Microsoft-Flow).

in sharepoint online, you can use Microsoft Graph too.

Answer (score 0):

As Sohail's reply, if you want to permanently delete the file using Microsoft flow, we need call rest api below to achieve it.

```
url: https://site url/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/file name')
method: POST
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
     X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    IF-MATCH: etag or "*"
    X-HTTP-Method:"DELETE"
```

Here is an example about how to delete all Subsites using REST API in Flow for your reference.

[Microsoft Flow | SharePoint Online | Delete all Subsites using REST API](https://sharepointmadeeasy.blogspot.com/2018/04/microsoft-flow-sharepoint-online-delete.html)

More information:

[HOW TO CALL SHAREPOINT REST WEBSERVICE FROM MICROSOFT FLOW](https://www.anupams.net/sharepoint-rest-service-microsoft-flow/)

Comment: Thanks @LZ_MSFT but is there any action in flow which permanent delete the file from document library.

Comment: It seems not an action in Flow to permanent delete the file from document library, we have to use REST API to achieve it.